# How to move to a specific second in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Is their any simple way in Windows Media Player to move to a specific second in a song/video without playing around with the slide?

(Like "`Go To Line...`" in text editors?)

---

**Edit:** If not possible, is there any other player that has this kind of feature?

Comment: I think "NO"...

Comment: Is their any other player that has this kind of feature?

Comment: @CD - in general, if you want to modify your question, or add details, do so by editing your question. This way, it will also be made more visible to more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Best player for me, this works with rare type of files as real media files. and support so many, so many codes.

**`just go to Playback-> Go to Specific Time.`**

Multiplatform, multilanguage, accepts Plugins extensions and the best is that it is Free. :)

Comment: Please Mark this question as answered. Just click on check image in the left of this post.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get to a particular point in a large file, I got close by clicking on the slider then I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to get closer to where I want. Then use the following hotkeys:

```
#IfWinActive, Windows Media Player

^left::                     ;;slow down WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}s{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return

^right::                        ;;speed up WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}g{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return

^down::                     ;;rewind WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}n{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return

left::                      ;;rewind WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}b{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return

right::                     ;;fastforward WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}f{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return

down::                      ;;normal/play WMP
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{shift Down}n{shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
return
```